# How to restrict registered user from using my website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have scenario where I want to restrict registered user to use my website to only one particular PC which he is registered for (One user registration = One PC). That user should not be able to logon to my website from any another PC using his registered username and password. How can I achieve this if getting Mac does not help. My website is built in asp.net and runs on IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter.

Comment: I think MAC restriction is the only way you can achive your scenario, others are not possible.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani don't forget that almost everyone goes through some NAT/proxies - so getting real MAC is not necessary possible.

Comment: Package your site up as a local installation.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That is also currect.

Answer (score 0):

There really nothing you can use to identify user+PC combination reliably in web environment. Reconsidering your requirement may be better approach.

If you really want to go with some strict "one instance only" some form of physical key may be an option... but it would be very inconvenient for users.

Note that even locally installed applications have hard time to reliably and at the same time somewhat user friendly identify such combinations.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex said, this might not be possible.

The MAC address isn't available to you. It's available to the router, but by the time it gets to you, it's been stripped off (actually, each router between you and the client machine replaces the MAC address with its own).

IP is not an option either as proxies may be involved or it may change.

But you could use `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID` to store as a non-expiring cookie on client system and also store this `SessionID` in a table with user's name. Later you can use the the cookie's value together with user's name/pass to get his record from DB.

But this is not guaranteed to work 100% either as the client system, of course, is free to toss the cookie (or not to accept it).